# How do i ensure no signal repaint in this pinescript code?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

> I have this script and I believe it repaints.What changes can I make
> so that it doesn't repaint on tradingview, please explain in detail
> why and if you could reference me to the necessary resources?
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x x x x x xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx x xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xx

```
//@version=2
    // Any timeFrame ok but good on 15 minute & 60 minute , Ichimoku + Daily-Candle_cross(DT) + HULL-MA_cross + MacD combination 420 special blend
    strategy("Custom 15m strat",overlay=true)
    keh=input(title="Double HullMA",type=integer,defval=14, minval=1)
    dt = input(defval=0.0010, title="Decision Threshold (0.001)", type=float, step=0.0001)
    SL = input(defval=-500.00, title="Stop Loss in $", type=float, step=1)
    TP = input(defval=25000.00, title="Target Point in $", type=float, step=1)
    ot=1
    n2ma=2*wma(close,round(keh/2))
    nma=wma(close,keh)
    diff=n2ma-nma
    sqn=round(sqrt(keh))
    n2ma1=2*wma(close[1],round(keh/2))
    nma1=wma(close[1],keh)
    diff1=n2ma1-nma1
    sqn1=round(sqrt(keh))
    n1=wma(diff,sqn)
    n2=wma(diff1,sqn)
    b=n1>n2?lime:red
    c=n1>n2?green:red
    d=n1>n2?red:green
    confidence=(security(tickerid, 'D', close)-security(tickerid, 'D', close[1]))/security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
    conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Periods")
    basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods")
    laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Lagging Span 2 Periods")
    displacement = input(26, minval=1, title="Displacement")
    donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
    conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
    baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
    leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
    leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)
    LS=close, offset = -displacement
    MACD_Length = input(9)
    MACD_fastLength = input(12)
    MACD_slowLength = input(26)
    MACD = ema(close, MACD_fastLength) - ema(close, MACD_slowLength) //macd
    aMACD = ema(MACD, MACD_Length) //signal
    closelong = n1<n2 and close<n2 and confidence<dt or strategy.openprofit<SL or strategy.openprofit>TP
    


//SHORTS 
shortCondition = n1<n2 and strategy.opentrades<ot and confidence<dt and close<n2 and leadLine1<leadLine2 and open>LS and MACD<aMACD
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "SHORT ETH")


if (closelong)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "SHORT ETH")
    //strategy.close("Long")
    
    
//LONGS   
    
longCondition = n1>n2 and strategy.opentrades<ot and confidence>dt and close>n2 and leadLine1>leadLine2 and open<LS and MACD>aMACD
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, comment = "LONG ETH")    
closeshort = n1>n2 and close>n2 and confidence>dt or strategy.openprofit<SL or strategy.openprofit>TP
if (closeshort)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, comment = "LONG ETH")
    //strategy.close("Short")
    
    

a1=plot(n1,color=c)
a2=plot(n2,color=c)
plot(cross(n1, n2) ? n1 : na, style = circles, color=b, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(n1, n2) ? n1 : na, style = line, color=d, linewidth = 4)
plot(conversionLine, color=#0496ff, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#991515, title="Base Line")
//plot(longCondition == true ? 4000:4100,title="long")
plot(close, offset = -displacement, color=#459915, title="Lagging Span")
p1=plot (leadLine1, offset = displacement, color=green,  title="Lead 1")
p2=plot (leadLine2, offset = displacement, color=red,  title="Lead 2")
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? green : red)
// remove the "//" from before the plot script if want to see the indicators on chart
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive repaint on it,

```
//@version=4
// Any timeFrame ok but good on 15 minute & 60 minute , Ichimoku + Daily-Candle_cross(DT) + HULL-MA_cross + MacD combination 420 special blend
strategy("Custom 15m strat",overlay=true)
keh=input(title="Double HullMA",type=input.integer,defval=14, minval=1)
dt = input(defval=0.0010, title="Decision Threshold (0.001)", type=input.float, step=0.0001)
SL = input(defval=-500.00, title="Stop Loss in $", type=input.float, step=1)
TP = input(defval=25000.00, title="Target Point in $", type=input.float, step=1)
ot=1
n2ma=2*wma(close,round(keh/2))
nma=wma(close,keh)
diff=n2ma-nma
sqn=round(sqrt(keh))
n2ma1=2*wma(close[1],round(keh/2))
nma1=wma(close[1],keh)
diff1=n2ma1-nma1
sqn1=round(sqrt(keh))
n1=wma(diff,sqn)
n2=wma(diff1,sqn)
b=n1>n2?color.lime:color.red
c=n1>n2?color.green:color.red
d=n1>n2?color.red:color.green


f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 

confidence=(f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close) - f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1])) / f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1])


conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Periods")
basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods")
laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Lagging Span 2 Periods")
displacement = input(26, minval=1, title="Displacement")
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)
LS=close, offset = -displacement
MACD_Length = input(9)
MACD_fastLength = input(12)
MACD_slowLength = input(26)
MACD = ema(close, MACD_fastLength) - ema(close, MACD_slowLength) //macd
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACD_Length) //signal
closelong = n1<n2 and close<n2 and confidence<dt or strategy.openprofit<SL or strategy.openprofit>TP
    


//SHORTS 
shortCondition = n1<n2 and strategy.opentrades<ot and confidence<dt and close<n2 and leadLine1<leadLine2 and open>LS and MACD<aMACD
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "SHORT ETH")


if (closelong)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, comment = "SHORT ETH")
    //strategy.close("Long")
    
    
//LONGS   
    
longCondition = n1>n2 and strategy.opentrades<ot and confidence>dt and close>n2 and leadLine1>leadLine2 and open<LS and MACD>aMACD
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, comment = "LONG ETH")    
closeshort = n1>n2 and close>n2 and confidence>dt or strategy.openprofit<SL or strategy.openprofit>TP
if (closeshort)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, comment = "LONG ETH")
    //strategy.close("Short")
    
    

a1=plot(n1,color=c)
a2=plot(n2,color=c)
plot(cross(n1, n2) ? n1 : na, style = plot.style_circles, color=b, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(n1, n2) ? n1 : na, style = plot.style_line, color=d, linewidth = 4)
plot(conversionLine, color=#0496ff, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#991515, title="Base Line")
//plot(longCondition == true ? 4000:4100,title="long")
plot(close, offset = -displacement, color=#459915, title="Lagging Span")
p1=plot (leadLine1, offset = displacement, color=color.green,  title="Lead 1")
p2=plot (leadLine2, offset = displacement, color=color.red,  title="Lead 2")
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.green : color.red)
// remove the "//" from before the plot script if want to see the indicators on chart
```